# How to delete all Lines not starting with.. [Notepad++]

Tags: notepad++

I've got a rather large file (Over 1GB) which I'm trying to filter out the mass of.  I'd like to delete all lines not containing a specific url in them.

I'm unsure how I'd do this and am not familiar with expressions in Notepad++ so as basic of an answer as possible would be great.

Edit:  I'd like to do this for multiple files at once so if possible using the find in files tab would be best.

Answer (score 15):

You could do:

1. Search the lines that contain the url:
   in the search box, give your url and in the tab "marks" click on Mark lines then search all
2. Then in menu Search > Bookmark > invert bookmarks
3. Then in menu Search > Bookmark > Remove bookmarked lines.

I haven't an english version of Noptepad++ so the name of functions could be a little bit different.

Comment: In English version it is `Search -> Bookmark -> Remove bookmarked lines`

Comment: I was going to suggest F3 followed by <Ctrl>+L, but I like this answer better! Especially the "Marks" tab in the search, never knew what it was for...

Comment: Please note that this only works if you check the "bookmark line" option on the Mark tab. As described, it will not.

Comment: @Mawg: That's what  said, I wrote "click on Mark lines" , I guess it is the same as "bookmark line". As I said I haven't English version of Npp.

Comment: My apologies, I am feeling a little "Monday morning" :-)

Comment: @Mawg: Don't worry ;)